# A reformulation of Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers

The Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem states the following:

> If $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are $\mathbb Q$-algebraic and $\mathbb Q$-linearly independent, then $\mathrm e^{\alpha_1},\dots,\mathrm e^{\alpha_n}$ are $\mathbb Q$-algebraically independent.

Baker's reformulation is the following:

> If $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ are distinct $\mathbb Q$-algebraic, then $\mathrm e^{\alpha_1},\dots,\mathrm e^{\alpha_n}$ are $\overline{\mathbb Q}$-linearly independent.

It is clear why Baker's reformulation implies the actual theorem, but how can the converse be proven?

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking about it and just got a proof (that seems way too elementary)don’t know if this is right.
Here’s the proof:

First note that $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ - algebraic independence is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$ - algebraic independence.

Consider the algebraic Field extention $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,…,\alpha_n)/\mathbb{Q}$   let $\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ be a basis of this extension. Devide $\beta_i$ a large enough integer if necessary, we will have $x_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $ x_{i1}\beta_1 + … + x_{in}\beta_n = \alpha_i $ for any $1 \leq i\leq n$ Moreover, $\alpha_i$’s are distinct, we get distinct solutions with distinct $i$ in the form $(x_{i1},…,x_{in})$. Now, by the original theorem, $\{e^{\beta_i}\}$ are algebraically independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. This immediately imply $\{e^{x_{i1}\beta_1 + … + x_{in}\beta_n}\}$ are linearly independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.